# How to move up an inner box and keep outer box in place with CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#yellow {height:100px; background:yellow;}
#blue {background:blue;}
#red {background:red; width: 400px; height: 100px; margin:0px auto;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="blue">
                <div id="red">Lots of content goes in here that will expand the outer blue box as well</div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the red box to move up about 30 pixels so that it overlaps both the yellow box and the blue box.  When i tried to do a `#red {margin:-30px auto 0px auto;}`, the blue box moved up 30 pixels with the red box as well, even though I wanted the blue box to stay in place.

How do i make the redbox move up and overlap both the yellow and blue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

```
#yellow {
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
}
#blue {
    background:blue;
}
#red {
    background:red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin:0px auto;
    position:relative;
    top:-30px;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want that space at the bottom of #blue, add margin-bottom:-30px to #red.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `position: relative`:

```
#red {
    position: relative;
    top: -30px;
    /* other CSS */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DJn8X/

This sample only requires relative positioning, but both relative and absolute positioning may be useful to you.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#positioning-scheme

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the blue box encompasses the red box. So you have to relatively position the red box.

So you just have to add the following piece of CSS code to the `#red` id.

```
#red { position: relative; top: -30px; }
```

This is the code as per your expected results;

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#yellow {height:100px; background:yellow;}
#blue {background:blue;}
#red {background:red; width: 400px; height: 100px; margin:0px auto; position: relative; top: -30px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="yellow"></div>
        <div id="blue">
                <div id="red">Lots of content goes in here that will expand the outer blue box as well</div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```